# Effect of isfun() on Constraint Solving

Tags: ats

It is my understanding that the following line of code effectively adds the fact that r12 = r0 to the "environment" under which Z3 will attempt to satisfy the constraints during typechecking:

prval () = is_fun(pf12, pf0)

Is it incorrect to think that this is actually reducing the number of constraints, because applying r12 = r0 may allow the solver to prove that two previously unique constraints are now equivalent? And, once we've reduced the number of constraints sufficiently, the inductive hypothesis along with our base case(s) will provide the remainder of the solution?

I am trying to get a general sense of what is happening behind the scenes to help understand how to build proofs in functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it adds an extra piece of information, which the constraint solver may use to solve constraints (generated in the appropriate scope where this new information is available).